# Comprehensive List of Seforim/Books Available or Sold

Tags: jewish-books, books-generally

I'm looking for a comprehensive list of all the books and seforim that would be sold at a Judaica store or a seforim store. I tried contacting a store but they didn't seem to have one. Does anyone have an idea of where I can get them?

This part is a stretch: but does anyone know of a way to know which ones sell more than others also?

Like if I'd want to open a Seforim store and I wanted to make sure I was stocked with the right books, and the right amount of the popular books. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: http://zbermanbooks.com/   http://www.eichlers.com/   http://www.israelbookshop.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc

Comment: contact the publishers - Artscroll, Feldheim, Zundel Berman, Israel Book Shop, etc.

Comment: A comprehensive list?!?! That would be _thousands_ (probably actually tens or houndreds of thousands) of books!

Comment: @Daniel: He is not looking for the list to be posted here, He is looking for a link or a source for this.

Comment: @GershonGold even so do you really think such a list even _could_ exist?

Comment: @Daniel: Stranger things exist

Answer (score 1):

[Lehmanns](http://www.lehmanns.co.uk/) have 12955 miscellaneous seforim and 1166 published by 'Oz VeHadar'. That doesn't count over 4000 in English.

I cannot help on popularity.